# what *should* you get when you add minus-zero to plus-zero?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

[this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) did not address this contingency and i am having trouble finding a definitive IEEE-754 document that addresses this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [one purported copy of the IEEE 754 (1985) standard](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs471/Lec3/ieee754.pdf),

> When the sum of two operands with opposite signs (or the difference of
>   two operands with like signs) is exactly zero, the sign of that sum
>   (or difference) shall be + in all rounding modes except round toward 
>   –INFINITY, in which mode that sign shall be –. However, x+x = x–(–x)
>   retains the same sign as x even when x is zero.

(section 6.3)

That applies to the (+0) + (-0) case, requiring the result to be +0 in most rounding modes, but -0 in round toward -INFINITY mode.

Comment: The 1985 standard was withdrawn and replaced with the 2008 standard. The 2008 wording is “When the sum of two operands with opposite signs (or the difference of two operands with like signs) is exactly zero, the sign of that sum (or difference) shall be +0 in all rounding-direction attributes except roundTowardNegative; under that attribute, the sign of an exact zero sum (or difference) shall be −0. However, x + x = x − (−x) retains the same sign as x even when x is zero.”

Comment: so, unless i am rounding down, +0 + -0 = +0.  but when i am rounding down, then it's +0 + -0 = -0.  and that result would test as negative, right?

Comment: Yes, @robertbristow-johnson, as long as by "rounding down" you mean the same thing that IEEE-754 does by rounding toward -INFINITY (1985) and rounding toward negative (2008).

Comment: that's what electrical engineers usually mean.  like the `floor()` function. it means *drop the bits* for a two's complement number.  (i realize that IEEE 754 is not like two's complement but is signed magnitude so *"drop the bits"* means *round toward zero*, but i meant always round down.  the funny thing is that the number you had before rounding down to get zero was non-negative, yet the test will say it was negative.  there are some goofy things about IEEE-754.  i coulda thought up a better floating-point standard.